# Unexplained crash while polling systemtime type

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a program that runs every 5 minutes when the stock market is open, which it does by running once, then entering the following function, which returns once 5 minutes has passed if the stock market is open.

What I don't understand, is that after a period of time, usually about 18 or 19 hours, it crashes returning a sigsegv error. I have no idea why, as it isn't writing to any memory - although I don't know much about the systemtime type, so maybe that's it?

Anyway, any help you could give would be very much appreciated! Thanks in advance!!

```
void KillTimeUntilNextStockDataReleaseOnWeb()
{
    SYSTEMTIME tLocalTimeNow;

    cout<<"\n*****CHECKING IF RUN HAS JUST COMPLETED OR NOT*****\n";
    GetLocalTime(&tLocalTimeNow);//CHECK IF A RUN HAS JUST COMPLETED. IF SO, AWAIT NEXT 5 MINUTE MARK
    while((tLocalTimeNow.wMinute % 5)==0)
        GetLocalTime(&tLocalTimeNow);

    cout<<"\n*****AWAITING 5 MINUTE MARK TO UPDATE STOCK DATA*****\n";
    GetLocalTime(&tLocalTimeNow);//LOOP THROUGH THIS SECTION, CHECKING CURRENT TIME, UNTIL 5 MINUTE UPDATE. THEN PROCEED
    while((tLocalTimeNow.wMinute % 5)!=0)
        GetLocalTime(&tLocalTimeNow);

    cout<<"\n*****CHECKING IF MARKET IS OPEN*****\n";
        //CHECK IF STOCK MARKET IS EVEN OPEN. IF NOT, REPEAT
    GetLocalTime(&tLocalTimeNow);
    while((tLocalTimeNow.wHour < 8)||(tLocalTimeNow.wHour) > 17)
        GetLocalTime(&tLocalTimeNow);

    cout<<"\n*****PROGRAM CONTINUING*****\n";
    return;
}
```

Comment: By the way, busy-waiting is really gross, especially for minutes at a time. (Your CPU usage will sit at 100%, and your computer will get really hot for long periods of time.) Prefer to sleep that time off instead.

Comment: And it's not entirely unheard-of for an overheating CPU to generate random-ish fault traps like a SEGV. Not saying that's your case, though, especially if it's always a SEGV and not something else - if it's repeatable/consistent, then overheating is a less likely culprit, even though it's still a possibility...

Comment: If you want to wait for the next 5 minute mark, you could just use `Sleep(300)`, which will sleap for 300 seconds, using 0% CPU time instead of 100% cpu time - your computer will then be able to do other useful things with the CPU while it's waiting. Rather than your process saying "Are we there yet?" like Donkey in the Shrek movie.

Comment: Great, thanks guys, I'll change this to Sleep(300) for the 5 minutes, and Sleep(.......whatever the amount of time between 5pm and 8am is in seconds!) Thanks for the quick responses!!

Comment: I hope you don't mind me writing up an answer based on my comment above.

Comment: Windows doesn't have SIGSEGV, it's access violation. But why don't you just use a debugger to tell you where the code crashed? Cause right now, I'm looking at "Off-topic because what have you tried."

Answer (score 2):

If you want to "wait for X seconds", then the Windows system call `Sleep(x)` will sleep for x milliseconds. Note however, if you sleep for, say, 300s, after some operation that took 3 seconds, that would mean you drift 3 seconds every 5minutes - it may not matter, but if it's critical that you keep the same timing all the time, you should figure out [based on `time` or some such function] how long it is to the next boundary, and then sleep that amount [possibly run a bit short and then add another check and sleep if you woke up early]. If "every five minutes" is more of an approximate thing, then 300s is fine.

There are other methods to wait for a given amount of time, but I suspect the above is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a busy loop, or even `Sleep()` in a loop, I would suggest using a [Waitable Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687012.aspx) instead.  That way, the calling thread can sleep effectively while it is waiting, while still providing a mechanism to "wake up" early if needed.